# Jetson nano module vs developer for production

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

Im building an application intended to run in producion at a museum on jetson nano. First my idea was to run it on the developer kit but I read that it might be a bad idea since it is not intended for production. But Im still wondering if I can use the developer board? Or will it not survive everyday use?

The module comes without carrier board so in the case I am using that one I need to build something myself or buy some addon for connecting usb hdmi etc. So that makes the developer kit more convenient.

I also need the GPIO which Im not sure you can access on the module?

Has anyone experience of running jetson developer kit on an everydaybasis?
Did you experience any problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have had experience with a burnt-out `Nano Developer Kit` after daily usage. However, I have had other `Nano Developer Kits` which still work fine. So I don't think you can conclude anything from that. The reason why the `Jetson Module` is meant for commercial purposes is that it comes with a warranty and is meant to be integrated with Industry-Grade Components. You decide based on your affordability to replace the Developer Kit in case something happens.

Regarding the GPIO, I am not sure if you can conclude that. They are several companies listed on [Nivida's website](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/community/jetson-partner-products) that build customized carrier boards. Decide based on your affordability.